# Loop through nested arrays, group their objects by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, javascript-objects

I have this nested array.

```
var arr = [
    [{ a }, { b }, { c }, { d }],
    [{ a }, { b }],
    [{ a }, { b }, { c }],
    [{ a }]
];
```

and I need it to be like this.

```
var arr = [
    [{ a }, { a }, { a }, { a }],
    [{ b }, { b }, { b }],
    [{ c }, { c }],
    [{ d }]
];
```

Here is where I've come so far (not very far):

```
(function() {
  var arr = [
    [{ a:"a" }, { b:"b" }, { c:"c" }, { d:"d" }],
    [{ a:"a" }, { b:"b" }],
    [{ a:"a" }, { b:"b" }, { c:"c" }],
    [{ a:"a" }]
  ];

  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var childArray2 = arr[i];
    console.log("i: " + i + ", j: " + j);
  }
})();
```

I've recked my brain and I'm stuck, thanks so much for help!

Comment: Can we assume equal objects are ever on the same index of the nested arrays? Also, note that your initial structure is not valid!

Comment: Add a [mcve] **in the question itself** and not only a link to an external resource (which may be offline, blocked or not reachable for some other reason...)

Comment: Yes, in the original array it is 0:a, 1:b, 2:c, 3:d in each of the four arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about your structure because the one you showed is not valid, so I have modifyed it a little. However, here you have one approach using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), this approach uses the assumption that: *equal objects are on the same index of the nested arrays*

```js
var arr = [
    [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"}, {d: "d"}],
    [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}],
    [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"}],
    [{a: "a"}]
];

let res = arr.reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    curr.forEach((v, i) => res[i] = res[i] ? [...res[i], v] : [v]);
    return res;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

An alternative version, that only use `for` loops could be the next one:

```js
var arr = [
    [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"}, {d: "d"}],
    [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}],
    [{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}, {c: "c"}],
    [{a: "a"}]
];

var newArr  = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
    {
        if (!newArr[j])
        {
            newArr[j] = [];
            newArr[j].push(arr[i][j]);
        }
        else
        {
            newArr[j].push(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works great. Would mind to write this in ES5, so I, as a js newbie, can understand it easier?

Comment: The  `reduce()` was available on `ES5`, so, do you want an implementation with just standard loops?

Comment: Yes, that would be super <3. I also don't quite understand the ? and the : in your code. I'm very basic, yet, sorry.

Comment: @neonduplex I added a new example that only use `for` loops.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
let a,b,c,d;
var arr = [
 [{ a }, { b }, { c }, { d }],
 [{ a }, { b }],
 [{ a }, { b }, { c }],
 [{ a }]
];

let pivotArr = arr => arr[0].map((x,i) => arr.map(x => x[i]));
pivotArr(arr);
```